# Creating a bridged network for HVM

Tags: centos, xen

I am trying to create an HVM, which I can do on my server but not attached to any NICs (even with trying to configure a bridged network). When I try to use xl to run the cfg file with the MAC address specified, it errors out on me:

```
Parsing config from /root/xen/devoracle.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route online [15257] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1462:domcreate_attach_vtpms: unable to add nic devices
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route offline [15372] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/block remove [15362] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/block failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/block remove [15365] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/block failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route remove [15495] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl.c:1583:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain 54
libxl: error: libxl.c:1542:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 54
libxl: error: libxl.c:1471:domain_destroy_cb: destruction of domain 54 failed
```

Every article I have read, even Xen's website, states that the first step is to create a bridged network. But when I run ifup, i always get:

`can't add eth0 to bridge xenbr1: Operation not supported`

Here is what my ifcfg-eth0 looks like:

```
GAETWAY=192.168.x.x 
SUBNET=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=xenbr0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

And ifcfg-xenbr0:

```
DEVICE=xenbr0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.x.x
IPADDR=192.168.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Both devices share the same Gateway. Is there something I am missing in this configuration?

Update:

Not sure if this is helpful, but when i attempt to run ifup icfg-xenbr0, i get:

`add bridge failed: Package not installed`

Comment: The `x` you use to mask your local IPs could easily prevent you from finding the answer.  Are you by any chance assigning the same IP to your bridge as `eth0`?  If so, you should not assign `eth0` an address.

Comment: Yes I am.. So in this case, do i assign it an IP at all (the bridged device)?

Comment: No, simply copy `eth0`'s MAC address to the bridge.  Do not assign `eth0` an IP.

Comment: I updated My question, I get the add bridge failed: package not installed when i do that

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: Not 100% but id like to say 7.x.. will check tomorrow..

Comment: You should look at http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/create-a-network-bridge-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html